# Roll back to ADT 20.0.3 and SDK Previous Version

Tags: android, sdk, adt, android-sdk-tools

i updated ADT and SDK version after that its giving problem in markupartist Action Library Which working properly before.
how can i roll back to old version of ADT and SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to uninstall the newer version and re-install the older version again.

Comment: there are no any otherway to roll back ?

Comment: Not of which i know. SDK manager doesnt give any options to roll back, neither does eclipse if you use online updates.